# In R, how can I add mulitple columns with 0/1 count based on another column?

Tags: r, dplyr, aggregate

Using the mtcars dataset in R as an example I want to add extra columns to the mtcars dataframe for each type of car.
With this line I can get the car models:

```
unique(sapply((strsplit(row.names(mtcars), " ")), "[[", 1))
```

Which would be 22 extra columns I want to add. A new column for each car model:

```
length(unique(sapply((strsplit(row.names(mtcars), " ")), "[[", 1)))
```

What I have come up with is this code:

```
mtcars01 <- mtcars
car.nms <- sapply((strsplit(row.names(mtcars), " ")), "[[", 1)
mtcars01$Mazda <- (car.nms=="Mazda")*1
mtcars01$Datsun <- (car.nms=="Datsun")*1
mtcars01$Hornet <- (car.nms=="Hornet")*1
```

And so on, and so on... Going through all the car models, until I have a new column added for each car model, with zeroes and ones. This is what I am after. I could then loop over all the unique car models, but I would prefer not to add a loop. If possible.

My own input data frame looks similar to the mtcars dataset, but I have a different number of car models, and would like to reuse this code for data frames where the number of car models vary. My own data frame might only have 3 car models, I would then need to have 3 extra columns appended to my data frame with zeroes and ones for these car models. I have marked this question with 'aggregate' and 'dplyr' as they appear promising. But I might be wrong on this part. Thanks for any help. Sorry if I overlooked an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be  to loop through the `unique` elements of 'car.nms', compare (`==`) with the values of 'car.nms' and coerce the logical matrix to binary (`+`)

```
mtcars01[unique(car.nms)] <- +(sapply(unique(car.nms), `==`,  car.nms))
```

---

Or using `tidyverse`, get the first word of the row names with `word` (from `stringr`), `pull` the rowname column, use `mtabulate` (from `qdapTools`) and bind the columns with the original data

```
library(tidyverse)
library(qdapTools)
rownames_to_column(mtcars) %>%
     mutate(rowname = word(rowname)) %>% 
     pull(rowname) %>% 
     mtabulate %>% 
     bind_cols(mtcars, .)
```

Comment: Yes. This almost returns what I am after. I do , however with this code, get extra columns for car models that appear in several rows. e.g. I get "Merc", "Merc.1", "Merc.2", "Merc.3" and so on, instead of only a single column for "Merc". In other words, I would prefer to have the value '1' in a single 'Merc' column for the rows named : Merc 240D, Merc 230,  Merc 280,  Merc 280C, Merc 450SE, Merc 450SL, Merc 450SLC.

Comment: @sku20003  I think you were using the earlier version where I didn't use the `unique`.  Please try it now

Comment: Brilliant. Yes. This works. Thank you so much, and thanks for ultra fast help. Very much appreciated.